# Chances of package being updated in stable release

Tags: updates

Found an issue in one of Ubuntu packages, which is already fixed in official git repository. I reported this bug on Launchpad. Now I wonder, how long will it take for this fix to end up on my system with system updates? Will I have to wait for another stable version (16.04) to get this fix?

Comment: Including the bug number/link wouldn't be a bad idea ;)

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-xkb-plugin/+bug/1510280

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  If it isn't that big of a deal, probably not; if it is a critical bug ( causes data loss, renders program entirely unusable ), then it probably will.  You might ask the bug triagers to look at it in #ubuntu-bugs on irc.freenode.net.